# How to close all positions at end of session? VWAP strategy error - Pine script

Tags: compiler-errors, pine-script, tradingview-api

Can somebody please help me out with this issue ?

The following Pine script code is intended *to buy if close is higher than VWAP and to sell if close is below VWAP* **EACH SESSION**.

```
//@version=5
strategy("VWAP Buy/Sell Strategy", shorttitle="VWAP Strategy", overlay=true)
import TradingView/Strategy/3
vwap = ta.vwap(close)
plot(vwap, color=color.white, title="vwap")

buyCondition = close > vwap
sellCondition = close < vwap

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = buyCondition)

strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when = sellCondition) 

Strategy.closeAllAtEndOfSession()
```

I tried to use `Strategy.closeAllAtEndOfSession()` **but only half the positions were closed**.

I need to fix this code so that at end of each session all my positions are closed before next session begins.

So, any thoughts on this? Thank you.